# Series convergence with exponentials

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would like to understand if the following series converge (any closed form for that?!):

1. $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\quad \frac{\exp(-n\cdot a)+n\cdot b}{(n+1)^2}$$
2. $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\quad \exp(-n\cdot a)\cdot\frac{1+n\cdot b}{(n+1)^3}$$

Thank you!

Comment: 1. is divergent unless $b=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don Antonio has already shown that the first series diverges.

For the second one, if $a\ge0$,

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathrm e^{-an}\frac{1+nb}{(n+1)^3}
&=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathrm e^{-a(n-1)}\frac{1+(n-1)b}{n^3}
\\
&=
\mathrm e^a\left((1-b)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\mathrm e^{-a}\right)^nn^{-3}+b\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\mathrm e^{-a}\right)^nn^{-2}\right)
\\
&=\mathrm e^a\left((1-b)\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\mathrm e^{-a}\right)+b\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\mathrm e^{-a}\right)\right)
\;,
\end{align}

where $\operatorname{Li}_s$ is the [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) of order $s$, which cannot be expressed in terms of more elementary functions.

Comment: So which will be the final result? I don't understand it!

Comment: The final expression diverges for every k, right?

Comment: @Stefano: Sorry, forget about the first version; the integrals in it can't be solved with elementary functions. I've reexpressed the result in terms of polylogarithms. As Don Antonio had already shown, the series converges for $a\ge0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\text{Assuming}\;\;b\ge 0:\;\;\frac{1+nbe^{na}}{e^{na}(n+1)^2}\ge\frac{bn}{(n+1)^2}$$

and the series with the rightmost general term diverges...(can you see what happens with  $\,b<0\,$ ?)

$$\text{As above: }\;\;\frac{1+bn}{(n+1)^3}\le\frac{2b}{n^2}$$

and the series with the rightmost general temr converges...

Comment: Assuming $a\ge0$.

Comment: Oops, yes. Thanks.

Comment: Anytime, @StefanoCoppola, and thanks to joriki for his comment: take into account.